# Poles of a magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

Why are the poles of a bar magnet not at the extreme ends of the magnet or why is the effective length not the real real length of a magnet?

Comment: Who says they're not? I thought that's what "bar magnet" meant--a long, skinny magnet, with poles at either end.

Comment: The distance between poles is 85% of actual lenth of magnet.. Our text book has it and we use it for numericals. My viva teacher asked me and I couldn't answer it so I came across this site. Well if my text book "principle of physics: part 2 (grade 12)" is wrong, let me know.. that will be a help. Thankyou for your response.

Comment: Source of the quote and exactly what it says would be useful.

Comment: Well the reason thats mentioned in the book is. "This is due to the fact that the atomic moments at the middle of the magnet are parallel and try to neutralize each other while at the wnds, they are not parallel but produce repulsion to some extent between them." Nothing more than that. From- principle of phyics Grade XII by Manu kumar khatry, Manoj kumar thapa, Bhesha Raj Adhikari, Arjun Kuamr Gautam and Parashu Ram Poudel published by Ayam Publication and Distributers Pvt. ltd. However, there is no clear explanation on why they are not at extreme end but only why they are not in the middle.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The concept of the effective length of the magnet is not that popular anymore because we have better magnets.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old rule of thumb from before rare earth magnets and is based on generalization and experimentation. I think there is a formula to find the effective length of the magnet due to this.

Early permanent magnet materials such as AlNiCo and chrome-cobalt had low coercivity. To simplify, there is a self-demagnetizing field that reduces the performance of the magnet, depending on the shape and the coercivity. In low coercivity materials, even if the magnet has a favorable shape (long in the direction of magnetic polarity) this effect reduces its performance, which makes it look as if the magnet is shorter than it actually is. Rare earth magnets (such as SmCo or NdFeB) have high coercivities that they will retain their performance even in unfavorable shapes. So this rule of thumb doesn’t apply to them. I would say that your book is not wrong but just needs a revision.